# Problem regarding maximum number of independent sets and maximum degree

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Can someone please help me with this problem.
Show that a graph with n vertices with maximum degree d satisfies
$a(G)>=\frac {|V(G)|} {d+1}$, where `a(G)` is the maximum number of independent sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think $a(g)$ should be the maximum size of an independent set. You can take a constructive approach. let $n=|V(G)|$

select a vertex and delte all of it's neighbors, there are now at least $n-(d+1)$ vertices. Select a vertex again and delete all of its neighbors(There are now $n-2(d+1)$ vertices. You can do this at least $\frac{n}{d+1}$ times. When you do this you shall have selected $\frac{n}{d+1}$ vertices and they will form an independent set since every time a vertex was selected we deleted all of its neighbors.

---

Note that if there is a vertex set $I$ of size $\frac{n}{d+1}$ it holds trivially that there are at least $\frac{n}{d+1}$ independent sets. Since any subset of $I$ will be independent and there are $2^\frac{n}{d+1}$ of those, which is more than $\frac{n}{d+1}$.

Comment: How did you obtain the number of times the process of selecting a vertex and removing its neighbors can be done.How did you get the number of times as $\frac{n}{d+1}$

Comment: each time you do that process you delete at most $d+1$ vertices. so after doing it $\lfloor\frac{n}{d+1}\rfloor$ (this is the largest integer that is smaller than or equal to $\frac{n}{d+1}$)  times you will have deleted at most $n$ vertices if $\frac{n}{d+1}$ is an integer then you will have allready done it enough times. If $\frac{n}{d+1}$ is not an integer then you will have deleted less than $n$ vertices. So you can take another vertices to get an independent set of more than $\frac{n}{d+1}$ vertices